# After undervolting using XTU, how to make the changes permanent?

Tags: undervolting

If I undervolt my laptop using XTU and then apply the changes, will the undervolt settings persist in the next boot or after shutting down and powering up ?

Does XTU have a service or something that applies the settings at each boot or shutdown+powerup ?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/3y1pk2/psa_your_undervolt_is_likely_not_sticking/ seems to have a solution; scheduling tasks to apply the settings after boot. Also lots of other random bits at https://www.google.com/search?q=xtu+save+settings+reboot.

Comment: is that link the case for all Intel laptops or do some Intel laptops work out of the box with XTU ?